# How to bypass two clicks needed to blur contenteditable div and click on outside button?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, contenteditable, onblur

I have a contenteditable div that holds its own state which allows me to perform checks on its own length and display warnings.

This editable div is called from a form-like component, which also holds its state, and retrieves the innerText of the contenteditable div when onBlur is fired.

However, if a user clicks on any button when the div was focused, it will only handle the onBlur() event, but not thereafter handle the onClick that was supposed to have occurred when the button was clicked. Therefore from a div focused state to a click (for example submit) two clicks are needed, when I would only like for there to be one.

The behavior I would like and expect would be this:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
   name: this.props.initialName
  }
  handleBlur(e) {
   console.log('handleBlur was called');
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
   console.log('handleSubmit was called');
  }
  render() {
   const { name } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{width:'400px'}}>
        <div>This is a contenteditable div: </div>
        <div
          style={{
            width: '70px',
            height: '20px',
            border: '1px solid gray'
            }}
          contentEditable
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        />
        <div
          onClick={this.handleSubmit}
          style={{backgroundColor:'#ddd'}}
        >Submit</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

In my code, the contentEditable div is imported from another file, and its own onBlur simply calls the handleBlur passed as a prop from my main form file. Is there something I am missing, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you make a CodeSandbox example and I'll take a look?

Comment: Solved, but thank you very much for offering to help!

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this thanks to a similar non-issue that was posted on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4210): What happened was I had my component that I imported change size upon onBlur (it hides the character counter) and therefore the Buttons underneath it move between the onBlur and the potential onClick event, therefore they aren't underneath the mouse pointer by the time the onClick event would fire.

A very easy fix is to have my component be of fixed size, between focused and blurred states so that the other buttons don't move.